# group operator and group vs. GROUP

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What does `group` do in the following two examples from http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#FOREACH:

> **Example: Nested Projection**
>
> In this example if one of the fields in the input relation is a tuple, bag or map, we can perform a projection on that field (using a deference operator).
>
> X = FOREACH C GENERATE group, B.b2;
>
> DUMP X;
>      (1,{(3)})
>      (4,{(6),(9)})
>      (8,{(9)})
>
> In this example multiple nested columns are retained.
>
> X = FOREACH C GENERATE group, A.(a1, a2);
>
> DUMP X;
>      (1,{(1,2)})
>      (4,{(4,2),(4,3)})
>      (8,{(8,3),(8,4)})

Is there any difference between using `group` and using `GROUP`?

Examples:

> **Example: Flattening**
>
> In this example the FLATTEN operator is used to eliminate nesting.
>
> X = FOREACH C GENERATE group, FLATTEN(A);
>
> DUMP X;
>      (1,1,2,3)
>      (4,4,2,1)
>      (4,4,3,3)
>      (8,8,3,4)
>      (8,8,4,3)
>
> Another FLATTEN example.
>
> X = FOREACH C GENERATE GROUP, FLATTEN(A.a3);
>
> DUMP X;
>      (1,3)
>      (4,1)
>      (4,3)
>      (8,4)
>      (8,3)

Answer (score 0):

From http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#GROUP

```
The first field is named "group" (do not confuse this with the GROUP operator) and is the same type as the group key.
```

Field names are case sensitive so there will not be a field "GROUP" created by a `GROUP` operator. In my opinion it is a minor error in the pig documentation.

Comment: The most relevant part to my question about "group" is "Continuing on, as shown in these FOREACH statements, we can refer to the fields in relation B by names "group" and "A" or by positional notation" (from [the link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#GROUP) given in the answer). Would someone explain "group"'s usage in that situation?